# How to calla method only once in a Controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, singleton, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST API and I want to call a method which creates the TreeMap from a csv file and I want to use the TreeMap for rest of the each API calls.So I just want to call the method to set the TreeMap and want to use the TreeMap for rest of the API calls.

My method for creating the TreeMap is

```
public void createTreeMap(){

 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\result.csv"), ',' , '"' , 1);
                    TreeMap <Integer,ArrayList<Long>> result=new TreeMap <Integer,ArrayList<Long>>();
                    //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
                    String[] nextLine;
                    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                       if (nextLine != null) {
                          //Verifying the read data here
                           ArrayList<Long> result_01 = new ArrayList<Long>(); 

                          for(int k=0;k<nextLine[1].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "").split(",").length;k++){
                              result_01.add(Long.parseLong(nextLine[1].replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(" ", "").split(",")[k]));
                          }


                          result.put(Integer.parseInt(nextLine[0]), result_01);



                       }
                     }  

}
```

So below is Rest api Controller

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {



@RequestMapping(value="/api/sid",produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<Model>>> getid(@RequestParam("sid") int sid) {




       Map<String, List<Model>> Map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       List<Model> model=new List<Model>();
       model=get_model();
       Map.put("hi",model)

      return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<Model>>>(Map,HttpStatus.OK);

    }


    @ResponseBody   

    public List<Model>  get_model(){
        List list =new List<Model>();
     //here I have to use the treemap

        return list;



    }

    }
```

I can create the tree map each time when the api is called.but instead of that I need to create it only once and access that in the response body get_model method.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what about using cache?

Comment: Where should I define the cache?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: cache createTreeMap.

Comment: how about using singleton pattern, which is checking if the tree map is null before instantiate it.

Comment: @HaoChih Could you explain in detail if u don't mind(examples would be more fine)

Comment: @RKR the Jaydeep Rajput's answer should be an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use singleton bean i.e create another bean to create the TreeMap from csv file and the TreeMap in member variable of bean.

```
@Bean
public class RefData{
     public TreeMap<Object> treeMap;

     public TreeMap<Object> getData(){
         if(this.treeMap == null){  
            //read csv file & prepare TreeMap & store it in this.treeMap
         }
         return this.treeMap;
     }
}
```

Comment: So this bean will be in the controller itself right

Comment: Better to have another class & inject it in your controller and whereever needed